# Как узнать процент покрытия кода тестами JUnit в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, юнит-тесты, junit

Как узнать процент покрытия кода тестами JUnit в IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Тут [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Help :: Running with Coverage](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-with-coverage.html) все подробно описано.

То есть запускаете тест с Покрытием

[image]

В правом боку **"Editor"** откроется таблица в которой показано покрытие кода в процентах и внизу появится пункт **"Coverage"**.

Answer (score 5):

Edit Configurations -> Add new configuration -> JUnit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Test kind: All in package и в поле package выберите корневой пакет проекта (Если вам нужно прогнать все тесты)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На закладке "Code Coverage" выберите корневой пакет проекта (опять же, если надо прогнать все тесты).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурацию настроили. Её необходимо запускать кнопкой "Run with Coverage" (см. картинку ниже). В результате вы получите процент покрытия, а в подарок увидите детализацию, какие именно строки покрыты, а какие - нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень важно указывать тип проеката JUnit. Нашёл это только в этом ответе.

Comment: Прошло три года, интерфейс идеи поменялся, но по ответу разобраться можно. Он актуален. Спасибо!